# Apart from reputation, why different accounts on different sites?

Tags: discussion

Ok, I understand why different sites require (calculate) different reputations.
But I find it a hassle to register (and fill in my details) for every single Stack Overflow site. Can't they just be combined somehow? Stack Overflow already knows me!
One small advantage of the current behavior: I can use a different plus address for every site. But then I also need an extra Gravatar entry...

Comment: [Some](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137184?tab=accounts#tab-top) [people](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2915?tab=accounts#tab-top) have the use for separated accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing already *does* happen, if you use the same OpenID on each site.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-automatic-account-association/

Apparently, you are not..

Comment: Yes I am. The only thing that differs is the e-mail address in the Stack Overflow settings. Does that matter?

Comment: I still don't understand. The e-mail address in the Stack Overflow settings should not matter. I think.
Using my Google Profile OpenID does associate fine: http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/323?tab=accounts

Answer (score 2):

You can copy profile details from an associated account to a new account you just opened, instead of filling everything in manually.

Comment: Typing them in is faster. It's not *that* much work. But it's an extra burden to log in to add a comment to some answer found through Google. So for some people it might be too much of a burden...

Comment: I now understand what Gnome meant: if SO detects equal OpenIDs (not Google accounts OpenIDs, which are different for different sites), one can (in some cases?) copy the data by clicking a button.

Comment: @Michel: Yes; sorry, I didn't realize that wasn't clear.  The accounts have to be associated first, and then you have to log in to the 'destination' account, view [associated accounts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147540?tab=accounts#tab-top), and select a profile to copy.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, because of OpenID's nature

ref: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/openid-one-year-later/

Comment: You mean the way Google (only) implements Gmail OpenIDs? I see. I guess I should have used equal (plus) addresses for the different sites... Thanks for clarifying!