# Why can't Area51 be associated?

Tags: support, status-completed, area-51, linked-accounts

My [Area51 account](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/323?tab=accounts) can somehow not be associated with [my other accounts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147540?tab=accounts). I'm almost 100% confident that [it did work before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51816/apart-from-reputation-why-different-accounts-on-different-sites), but now I only have a button "Clear All Associations". [Pressing that one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54407/why-cant-i-associate-my-meta-account) does not help.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be working again.  We're making behind-the-scenes changes to get ready for launching the first site and temporarily broke associations.

Comment: I'm still seeing the current site on the associated sites lists here and on SO, SU and SF though. Is this correct or hasn't the fix propagated out to the other sites yet?

Comment: @ChrisF that's a different issue...please open another [bug]

Comment: Done - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54627/the-current-site-appears-on-the-list-of-related-accounts

Comment: Works, kind of. I see all my accounts in my Area51 profile. But I do NOT see my Area51 account in my other profiles!

Comment: For that last thing, I created http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54805/why-is-my-associated-area51-account-not-shown-in-so-et-al.

Answer (score 2):

I've just discovered the same issue. I just created an Area 51 account with the same OpenID I use for SO, SU, SF, and Meta. It grabs my gravatar correctly, but I cannot associate my account (and, consequently, my "total rep" is my A51 rep only).

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same issue here too, all my other accounts are associated OK, but my A51 account with the same OpenID can't be associated... This makes me sad :(

Answer (score 0):

Under the accounts page I get buttons to associate to all my other accounts but when I click them I get the error...

```
user Id xxxxx already associated with another account
```

Weirdly I had the message saying they had been auto associated and got the points the other day, so they must have been associated at one time.

Comment: I got same error - a few days ago I associated my three trilogy accounts, but didn't see an option to add Area51. Today I go to Area51 and see an option to associate the other three, and error. Are we able to associate only from one original account, maybe?