# Area 51 related accounts not working

Tags: bug, area-51, linked-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t Area51 be associated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54566/why-cant-area51-be-associated)

Just signed it on Area 51 and in the accounts tab there aren't any of my other accounts: stackoverflow, superuser, meta stackoverflow.

Is this normal?

Comment: probably strongly related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54596/ive-just-associated-my-account-with-the-same-account

Comment: it's not the same question. I don't see any associations on the Area 51 site.

Comment: It's the same question as the "Possible duplicate" one, though. But chances are high that the one I linked to is related.

Comment: @balpha The URL in your comment doesn't work (question was removed). The URL in the question, as possible duplicate, works just fine though.