# The current site appears on the list of related accounts

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-accounts

I've also just spotted that the current site appears on the related accounts tab. Meta here on Meta, SO on SO etc.

[image]
<sub>(source: [free-online.co.uk](http://www.forman.free-online.co.uk/images/related-accounts.png))</sub>

Promoting [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54566/why-cant-area51-be-associated/54571#54571) to a question.

Comment: Same issue as this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54596/ive-just-associated-my-account-with-the-same-account

Comment: @Jon - Ah - I just posted this in response to David's comments here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54566/why-cant-area51-be-associated/54618#54618

Comment: I'm pleased to see the [consecutive day count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/865/consecutive-day-count-in-profile) get implemented.

Comment: I love that you censored your age.

Comment: @perbert - I got carried away when blacking out the OpenIDs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue in an equality operator - it's been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue on StackOverflow