# Why is my associated Area 51 account not shown in SO et al.?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, area-51, association

The bug [Why can’t Area 51 be associated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54566/why-cant-area51-be-associated) has been fixed, or at least half of it. Today it somehow needed `Clear All Associations` and reassociating again, but [my Area 51 profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/323?tab=accounts) now shows the other sites as associated.

Now for the other half. [My SO account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/357313?tab=accounts) (for example) does not show Area 51. It doesn't even find the Area 51 account suggesting it for association. It should just show the existing association.

Is there still something broken or am I missing something? Is it because Area 51 has the highest reputation in my case, perhaps?

Comment: It's not to do with your relative reputation. There is no link from my SO account to Area 51 either, and I have much more SO rep than Area 51 rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because Area 51 is still in Beta.